# Run-time error on finding last used column

Tags: vba, excel

I Have an excel VBA  code to merge sheets in workbooks of a folder.First it wants to copy all cells to output sheet from the first sheet.Next sheet onwards, it wants to copy from the 2nd row till last used row.The column headings of input sheets may not be in same order.It is showing an automation error on debugging the below line for finding last used column

```
   **lco = ws2.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column**
```

[image: Error message]

the entire code is following:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
directory = "C:\Users\Desktop\MYExcel\Input\"
fileName = Dir(directory & "*.xl??")
  i = 0
  j = 0
     'create new output file
   Set Wk = Workbooks.Add
            With Wk
                .Title = "All Sheets"
                .SaveAs fileName:="C:\Users\Desktop\MYExcel\Output\AllSheets.xlsx"
                .Close
             End With

 Do While fileName <> ""
           If i = 0 Then
           Set x = Workbooks.Open(directory & fileName) 'Opening the first workbook in directory
           Set y = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Desktop\MYExcel\Output\AllSheets.xlsx") 'opening the output workbook
     Set ws2 = y.Sheets(1)
        If j = 0 Then
              Set ws1 = x.Sheets(1)

                With ws1
                    .Cells.Copy ws2.Cells 'Copying all cells to output sheet for s
                    y.Close True
                    'x.Close False
                End With
                j = j + 1
        End If
        If j > 0 Then
            For Each sheet In x.Worksheets
                'Set ws2 = y.Sheets(1)
               ' lColumn = ws.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
                 lci = sheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
                 **lco = ws2.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column**
                 lri = sheet.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
                 lro = ws2.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
                For Each cell In rng
                    For Each cell2 In rng2
                         l = ActiveCell.Column
                        If cell.Value = cell2.Value Then
                            With sheet
                                .Cells(cell, 2).EntireColumn.Copy ws2.Cells(cell2).Range(lro)
                            End With
                        End If
                    Next cell2
                Next cell
            Next sheet
        End If
    Workbooks(directory & fileName).Close
    fileName = Dir()
    i = i + 1

Else

    Set d = Workbooks.Open(directory & fileName)
    Set f = Workbooks.Open("AllSheets.xls*")
    'Windows("Book3.xlsm").Activate
    For Each sheet In x.Worksheets
            Set ws4 = f.Sheets(1)
             lci = sheet.Cells(1, sheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
             lco = ws4.Cells(1, ws4.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
             lri = sheet.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
             lro = ws4.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

            Set rng = sheet.Range("A1:A" & lci)
            Set rng2 = ws4.Range("A1:A" & lco)

            For Each cell In rng
                For Each cell2 In rng2
                     l = ActiveCell.Column
                    If cell.Value = cell2.Value Then
                         With sheet
                            .Cells(cell, 2).EntireColumn.Copy ws4.Cells(cell2).Range(lro)
                         End With
                    End If
                Next cell2
            Next cell
    Next sheet
 End If
Loop
```

Comment: please show us the error message.

Comment: Put a break on that line, then check to ensure that the workbooks are Open, and that ws2 has been set to the correct sheet and workbook.

Comment: @RonRosefeld can you please tell me the code to make 'ws2' as active workbooks active sheet and at where it want to be set?

Answer (score 0):

Code you have used to get LastColumn is absolutely fine. It is working at my end.

Only you need to check that you have commented the line

```
Set ws2 = y.Sheets(1)
```

Please uncomment the same and check, it must work.